# How to restrict access to only some columns in Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Access 2013, I have a view linked to the SQL server. The Access table updates to the view's contents, and writes the changes back to the server when I edit it. Basic stuff.

Say a user has read-write access to this view and its associated tables on the SQL server. Naturally, they will be able to edit all columns using Access. How would I restrict them from editing some chosen columns in Access, to prevent accidental changes in primary keys and other important data?

Comment: Can you explain why you posted this Q&A?

Comment: @Morpheus: This is a problem I was having and I couldn't find a simple solution online. SO has an option to "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" and I did it for the benefit of others.

Comment: Good to know.  Here's a link for others that may have wondered the same thing:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature in Access due to performance concerns when scaling the table up to large sizes.

A simple workaround is to add an empty string or other trivial value to the view definition on the SQL server. For example, change `[Product ID]` to `[Product ID]+''`

When using views, Access will take any edits you do and propagate it through the view back to the original tables, but it cannot do this for derived fields with calculations. By making the column derived, Access will be unable to edit the column, effectively restricting the user as well. Other columns in the view will still update normally.